# How to separately shut down App Engine services?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-php

I have several services in App Engine, how can I shut down (stop) them separately?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the official documentation below explaining the components of the App Engine [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine):

> An App Engine app is made up of a single application resource that
>   consists of one or more services. Each service can be configured to
>   use different runtimes and to operate with different performance
>   settings. Within each service, you deploy versions of that service.
>   Each version then runs within one or more instances, depending on how
>   much traffic you configured it to handle.

From the google cloud console you can delete a service; delete, stop, start a version of a service; delete an instance of a version. So I think you should stop a version of your service.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it from the web console:

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/services

select the one you want to delete and click delete

Comment: This will delete the service, not stop it.

Answer (score 0):

To shut down services in App Engine to go [App Engine > Versions](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions) in Google Console.

Then select your service via dropdown > check version and then "STOP".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scaling type of the version of your Application, the feature of Startup and Shutdown differs [1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types). With Automatic Scaling instances are automatically turned down when idle. Basic and Manual Scaling allow the desired feature.

You could also do it via gcloud command, by stopping versions of the service (one or multiple) [2](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/stop), [3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_states):

- $gcloud app versions stop --service servicename v1 (one)
- $gcloud app versions stop --service servicename v1 v2 (multiple)